# Alarms on an ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

I am using an ESP32 connected to Google Cloud IoT Core to control lights with a raspberry pi as a hub to send messages to the esp32 through IoT core to turn them on and off at set times of the day.

What I want to do now is just eliminate the raspberry pi and have the esp32 manage when it needs to turn them on or off but I cant see to find a way to set alarms or something like alarms that trigger at specific times of days.

The time value coming in is in milliseconds from UTC

Does something like that exists or how could I accomplish alarms on the esp32?

Comment: Any 20 cent microcontroller can control outputs on a schedule, so I suspect there's something you left out of the question, such as wanting to change the configuration over the network from Google Cloud.

Comment: And why did this question get the [tag:arduino] tag?

Comment: @BenVoigt on a schedule such as every x number of milliseconds but I am talking about specific time of day

Comment: [time library?](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time)

Comment: @tyczj: Any 20 cent microcontroller can do that too.  "Every x number of milliseconds, count elapsed seconds.  When elapsed seconds = scheduled time, produce output."  All that's necessary beyond that is either a battery-backed calendar peripheral to keep track of wall clock time when the power's disconnected, or synchronizing calendar on the network at least once after power-on.

Comment: @BenVoigt I already sync the time when it powers up with `configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");` but dont I still have to worry about the time rollover when calling `time(nullptr)`?

Comment: That depends on how large your `time_t` is.  There will be no problem if you compile with 64-bit `time_t`.

Comment: Are you using the ESP-IDF? Are you using FreeRTOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you are using the ESP IDF or some sort of Arduino framework for the ESP32 (with which I am not familiar). This answer is for the ESP IDF. If you are not using the ESP-IDF and don't have access to the relevant header files and libraries, some of the ideas might still be relevant.

### Activate SNTP

Ensure that the clock on the controller is updated by following the SNTP example at https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/sntp .

### Use `localtime()`

If you are using the ESP-IDF you will have access to the `localtime_r()` function. Pass this (a pointer to) the number of 'seconds since the Epoch' - as returned by `time(NULL)` - and it will fill a `struct tm` with the day of the week, day of the month, hour, minute and second.

The general procedure is (error handling ommitted) ...

```
#include <time.h>
// ...

struct tm now = {};
time_t tnow = time(NULL);
localtime_r(&tnow, &now);
// Compare current day, hour, minute, etc. against pre-defined alarms.
```

Note: You can use `gmtime_r()` instead of `localtime_r()` if you prefer to use UTC.

You can invoke this periodically from your main `while()` loop as outlined below.

### Alarm structures

Define a structure for your alarm information. You could use something like the following - tweaking according to the level of granularity you need. Note that it includes a `callback` member - to specify what the program should actually do when the alarm is triggered.

```
typedef struct {
    int week_day;  // -1 for every day of week
    int hour;      // -1 for every hour
    int minute;    // -1 for every minute
    void (*callback)(void);
    void *callback_arg;
} alarm_t;
```

### Define alarms and callbacks

Define your array of alarms, callback functions and arguments.

```
static void trigger_relay(const void *arg) {
    uint32_t num = *(uint32_t *)arg;
    printf("Activating relay %u ...\n", num);
    // Handle GPIO etc.
}

static uint32_t relay_1 = 0;
static uint32_t relay_2 = 1;

static alarm_t alarms[] = {
    // Trigger relay 1 at 9:00 on Sunday
    {0, 9, 0, trigger_relay, (void *)&relay_1},
    // Relay 2 at 7:30 every day
    {-1, 7, 30, trigger_relay, (void *)&relay_2},
};
```

### Periodic scan

Define a `check_alarms()` routine which loads a `struct tm` structure with the current time and compares this with each of the alarms you have defined. If the current time matches that of the alarm, the callback is invoked.

```
static void check_alarms(void) {
    time_t tnow = time(NULL);
    struct tm now = {};
    localtime_r(&tnow, &now);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Time: %u:%u:%u", now.tm_hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec);
    size_t n_alarms = sizeof(alarms) / sizeof(alarms[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_alarms; i++) {
        alarm_t *alrm = &alarms[i];
        if (alrm->week_day != -1 && alrm->week_day != now.tm_wday) {
            continue;
        }
        if (alrm->hour != -1 && alrm->hour != now.tm_hour) {
            continue;
        }
        if (alrm->minute != -1 && alrm->minute != now.tm_min) {
            continue;
        }
        alrm->callback(alrm->callback_arg);
    }
}
```

This would then be called from your main `while()` loop with a frequency depending on the granularity of your alarm. Since the `alarm_t` defined above has a granularity of 1 minute, that is how often I will call `check_alarms()`. This example is for FreeRTOS but could be adapted as needs be.

```
while (1) {
   TickType_t tick = xTaskGetTickCount();
   if (tick - g_time_last_check > pdMS_TO_TICKS(60000)) {
       g_time_last_check = tick;
       check_alarms();
   }
}
```

### Efficiency

The above is not very efficient if you have a lot of alarms and / or each alarm should be triggered at high frequency. In such a case, you might consider algorithms which sort the alarms based on time until elapsed, and - instead of iterating over the entire array every time - instead employ a one-shot software timer to invoke the relevant callback. It probably isn't the worth the hassle unless you have a very large number of timers though.

### Alternatives

Both FreeRTOS and the ESP-IDF include APIs for [software timers](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/esp_timer.html) - but these can not be (easily) used for alarms at a *specific time of the day* - which you state as a requirement. On the other hand - as you may already know - the ESP32 system-on-a-chip does have a built-in RTC, but I think it is best to use a higher-level interface than communicating with it directly.

Answer (score 0):

A [real-time clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) is what you are looking for. I've never worked with the ESP32 but apparently [it has one and it is bad](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/994). However, 5% error might be good enough for you. If it's an option, I would use an external one.